# CloudFormation incorrectly reporting drift in CloudFront tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, drift

I have a CloudFormation stack that provisions a CloudFront distribution.
Whenever a resource is provisioned under a CloudFormation stack, CloudFormation attempts to tag that resource with any tags on the stack (according to the documentation of the `--tags` parameter on the [`create-stack` command page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html)).

Just the same, my CloudFormation stack attempts, and is successful in tagging the CloudFront distribution. However, when I run drift detection on the stack **immediately** after the distribution is created, CloudFormation detects drift on the distribution.
[image]
As you can see here, CloudFormation doesn't even recognize the existence of any tags on the distribution, signified by the `REMOVE` difference. However, the tag is clearly and demonstrably applied to the distribution.
[image]
I even added an extra tag to see if it gets picked up by drift detection, but it does not.

I can inline it if necessary, but the template for the stack in question is in [my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539194/cryptic-cloudformation-failure-when-creating-cloudfront-distribution).

**Why is drift detection erroneously excluding these tags?**

This probably will not have any impact on my stack as a whole or my ability to use and update these resources, but having a bad drift report kills my OCD.

Comment: The template you linked in other question, does not have any tags. You are adding the tags manually?

Comment: No. The tag is on the stack, which gets propagated to resources managed by the stack, as explained in the documentation link I posted.

Comment: I think that would explain that. Drift detection is not aware that you used `--tags` when deploying the stack.

Comment: Drift detection detects that tag on the other stack resources just fine. Besides, the issue is obviously that drift detection is outright not detecting any tags on the distribution, exemplified by the fact it doesn't recognize the tag that I added manually.

Comment: Drift detection is not universal. In this list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html), CloudFront distributions are not included. Thus its seems its not supported.

Comment: [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html) says that when a property cannot be tracked by drift detection, it is excluded from drift detection results. That's not what happened here. Also, the list of resource types that support drift detection in the list you linked does not include private provisionable resources, as indicated in the header. It's hard to say if CloudFront distributions fall into that category, but I don't see any other reason why it wouldn't just be excluded from drift results otherwise.

Comment: It could be CloudFormation bug. Not the first one, nor the last one. You could report it on github: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues

Comment: Posted:
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/901

Comment: Hopefully they will be able to clarify what's happening.

Comment: We're running into the same issue. It looks like tags that you add to your stack also end up on the cloudfront distro resource.... so any tags that you only add to the stack don't end up in the distro when it gets created, but on the next check cloudformation find the drift because it thinks it needs to add the stack tags to the distro.... gonna have to contact AWS support on this one lol